# update multiple rows using limit in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

```
    UPDATE messages set test_read =1 
        WHERE userid='xyz' 
        ORDER BY date_added DESC  
        LIMIT 5, 5 ;
```

I am trying to use this query to update a set of 5 rows using limit but mysql is showing an error..The one below is working

```
    UPDATE messages set test_read =1 
        WHERE userid='xyz' 
        ORDER BY date_added DESC  
        LIMIT 5 ;
```

why is the first one not working?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you really must do it this way, you can use something like this:

```
 UPDATE messages SET test_read=1
 WHERE id IN (
     SELECT id FROM (
         SELECT id FROM messages 
         ORDER BY date_added DESC  
         LIMIT 5, 5
     ) tmp
 );
```

Comment: Do you really need the double nested select?  In ms sql it would just be something like "Where id in (SELECT TOP 5 id FROM messages ORDER BY date_added DESC)"

Comment: Yes, MySQL doesn't allow you do update a table that it selects from. The extra nested select forces it to save the results into a temporary table.

Comment: When you ask `if you really must do it this way`, are you implying there is a better alternative to updating records based on a rank given by the order of one of its fields?

Comment: When I first looked at this answer, I thought surely this won't work, but it did! Great answer and thank you.

Comment: MySQL 5.5 does not support LIMIT in IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery.

Answer (score 5):

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=42415

> The documentation states that any UPDATE statement with LIMIT clause
>   is considered unsafe since the order of the rows affected is not
>   defined:
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-features-limit.html
>
> However, if "ORDER BY PK" is used, the order of rows is defined and
>   such a statement could be logged in statement format without any
>   warning.