# UPDATE query is not working with LIMIT

Tags: php, mysql, limit

hi i am using an UPDATE query with limit 0,1 where i have to update the first row which matches the condition which i m giving in the query

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `product_option` SET `input_value`='$color_a',`input_price`='$color_price_a' WHERE `product_id`='$_REQUEST[pid]' and `input_type`='option' LIMIT 0,1");
```

in my sql table the $_request[pid] is repeating many times so on that rows in which $_request[pid] is matching, i want to update the first row on it but this query is not doing any thing the data is still same which i have added.

any suggestion will be appreciated

here is the image of the table

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with *"**first** row that matches ..."*? There is no order in a relational table. If uoi want to use `LIMIT`, you should provide an `ORDER BY` as well. Otherwise, a random row (that matches the criteria) will be updated.

Comment: Please bear in mind that updating with Limit is not replication safe. In other words, in a replicated mysql environment there is the potential for the command to update a different row on the master than it did on the slave http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-features-limit.html

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289729/mysql-update-query-with-limit

Comment: Take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513206/update-multiple-rows-using-limit-in-mysql LIMIT is not supported with UPDATE alone.

Comment: `LIMIT` is supported. `LIMIT` with `OFFSET` is not.

Comment: Why would you need to do this? There are antoincrement and unique column types. Use that to update only one row.

Answer (score 5):

It should be `LIMIT 1`

`LIMIT 0,1` means `OFFSET 0 LIMIT 1`, but `UPDATE` does not support offsets.

Even if it would work (which it doesn't) you still **always** have to supply an `ORDER` clause or it will be a random row.

Comment: no actually limit 0,1 is working when i am calling the data from table it displays the first from the multiple rows which  matches the conditions. i dont know on updating its working or not

Comment: @HarishKumar see my edited answer; is's valid syntax for selects but not for updates

Comment: @Harish: `LIMIT 0,1` works with `SELECT` but not with `UPDATE`.

Comment: i have upload the table image also this will help i think for understanding what i need to do. here i want to update the first row so can it be possible with update query