# max in where clause update mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm just stuck with a simple mysql query, I want to update the row having max Id of a table, and I was trying something like but it doesn't work

```
UPDATE inbox i
INNER JOIN messages m ON i.message_id = m.id 
SET i.read = 0
WHERE m.conversation_id = 10
AND i.user_id = 1
ORDER BY i.id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

I've also tried sub query but it doesn't work either

Need some help on it.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry my mistake, there is a join in my update query so I didn't put the right query before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySql you can't update a table if you have a subquery that references the same table, but you could sostitute the subquery with JOINS. I would do this, it's a trick but it works:

```
UPDATE
  inbox inner join (select max(id) as maxid from inbox) mx on inbox.id = mx.maxid
SET inbox.`read` = 0
```

**EDIT:** I see you edited your question, so i have to edit my answer:

```
UPDATE
  inbox
  INNER JOIN (select max(inbox.id) as maxid
              from
                inbox inner join messages
                on inbox.message_id = messages.id
              where
                messages.conversation_id=10
                and inbox.user_id=1) mx
  on inbox.id = mx.maxid
SET inbox.`read` = 0
```

Your subquery returns the maximum id based on the `conversation_id` and the `user_id` you want, then you join `inbox` whith the maximum id to select just the row you want, and you can then update just that row.

Comment: i also found this solution, with a different approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513206/update-multiple-rows-using-limit-in-mysql but i like my solution more :)

Comment: Thanks for replying, I've tried it UPDATE
inbox i
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(inbox.id) AS maxid
              FROM inbox INNER JOIN messages
              ON inbox.message_id = messages.id
              WHERE
              messages.conversation_id=10
              AND inbox.user_id=1) mx
ON inbox.id = mx.maxid
SET i.read = 0 but I'm getting  Unknown column 'inbox.id' in 'on clause'

Comment: If I put it just max(id) instead of max(inbox.id) it give Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: i fixed max(inbox.id) and i had an alias on set, fixed that also. now my code should be ok... i see you are using an alias for inbox, try to use this ON clause: `on i.id = mx.maxid`

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape [reserved words in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) like `read` with backticks. You can also use `limit` to update just the greatest record.

```
UPDATE inbox
SET `READ` = 0
order by id desc
limit 1
```

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/998b1/1)

Comment: is this really working? I didn't know you can add `ORDER BY` clause in `UPDATE` statements.