# SQL: UPDATE with INNER JOIN with LIMIT

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, sql

I am trying to update specific column in my database.

This query works:

```
UPDATE table1 A INNER JOIN table2 B 
ON A.type = B.typeName
SET A.closed = 0, A.sample = 0 
WHERE A.`status` IN ('Finished', 'Exception', 'Query') AND A.date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-01-31' 
AND A.code IN ('ex1','ex2','ex3') 
AND A.closed = 0 AND B.order = 'Non-Order' AND A.userName = 'test';
```

But when I tried to put a limit, it says:

```
Incorrect usage of UPDATE and LIMIT

UPDATE table1 A INNER JOIN table2 B 
ON A.type = B.typeName
SET A.closed = 0, A.sample = 0 
WHERE A.`status` IN ('Finished', 'Exception', 'Query') AND A.date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-01-31' 
AND A.code IN ('ex1','ex2','ex3') 
AND A.closed = 0 AND B.order = 'Non-Order' AND A.userName = 'test' LIMIT 3;
```

How can I make this Update with the limit? thanks a lot!

```
[EDIT]
```

I already do what I want, but it is slow, took 6 secs to update 3 rows.

Here's the query:

```
UPDATE table1 SET closed=1, sample=1
 WHERE id IN (
     SELECT id FROM (
         SELECT id FROM table1 A
         INNER JOIN table2 B ON A.type = B.typeName
         WHERE A.`status` IN ('Finished', 'Exception', 'Query') AND A.date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-01-31' 
    AND A.code IN ('ex1','ex2','ex3') 
    AND A.closed = 0 AND B.order = 'Non-Order' AND A.userName = 'test' LIMIT 3
     ) tmp
 );
```

How can I optimize this query thanks again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just can't.

According to [MySQL docs for UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html):

```
For the multiple-table syntax, UPDATE updates rows in each table named in
table_references that satisfy the conditions. In this case, ORDER BY and LIMIT
cannot be used.
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
UPDATE  table1 a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  id 
            FROM    table1 A
                    INNER JOIN table2 B 
                        ON A.type = B.typeName
            WHERE   A.status IN ('Finished', 'Exception', 'Query') AND 
                    A.date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-01-31' AND 
                    A.code IN ('ex1','ex2','ex3') AND 
                    A.closed = 0 AND 
                    B.order = 'Non-Order' AND 
                    A.userName = 'test' 
            LIMIT   3
        ) tmp ON a.ID = tmp.ID
SET     a.closed = 1, 
        a.sample = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

`LIMIT` can only be used on `SELECT` statements. If you want to limit the no. of records affected for your UPDATE statement, you'll have to use WHERE.

Comment: that's not true. `LIMIT` can still be used on `UPDATE` statements but not when updating multiple tables.

Comment: @JW. Any reference would be appreciated.

Comment: I have a program that uses LIMIT when updating, but not with inner join

Comment: Oh okay. Also found another reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513206/update-multiple-rows-using-limit-in-mysql