# Update first row of duplicate rows from sql table

Tags: sql

In sql table I select duplicate IDs which count is > 1 .Then I need to update only first row of selecting duplicate id rows.How to update just first row value.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: A) "First" is undefined in SQL. You'll at least need to have a sort order in mind. B) You probably shouldn't have duplicate IDs, assuming the "ID" is supposed to be the primary key. Also, it would be helpful if you could include what flavour of SQL you're using.

Comment: I might be wrong, but it feels like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513206/update-multiple-rows-using-limit-in-mysql) is very similar to yours.

Comment: Hello Flavour is MSql 2008 r2.These IDs is in VIEW.because of it they are duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have something like this:

```
SELECT ID
FROM ProductView
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

You will need to create a loop around the query and then select a result using TOP 1 and matching the ID.  You can create the loop using a [cursor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).