# MySQL: Updating rows with Select and Limit

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I am trying to UPDATE all rows on a table to the iterating values of a for loop based on a LIMIT, so that the update would be done in batches. I took a cue from a suggestion in the post [update multiple rows using limit in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513206/update-multiple-rows-using-limit-in-mysql), but it seems to be giving me a problem. The table has over 2400 rows, and the relevant field has all-0 values. Here's my code:

```
for($i = 0;$i < 7; $i++) {
    $qq2_ = $db1->prepare("UPDATE ledum_orgs SET ledum_org_size = :val WHERE ledum_org_size IN (
                            SELECT ledum_org_size FROM (
                                SELECT ledum_org_size FROM ledum_orgs WHERE ledum_org_size = '0'
                                ORDER BY ledum_org_name ASC
                                LIMIT ".($i*400).", 400
                            ) tmp
                          )"
                         );
    $qq2_->bindValue(':val',$i);
    $qq2_->execute();
    echo $i."=>".$qq2_->rowCount().", ";
}
```

But it seems to be disregarding the LIMIT clause, setting the field for all 2445 rows to '1'. Here's the output:

0=>0, 1=>2445, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0, 5=>0, 6=>0,

Can someone tell me why this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you cannot use `limit` in a subquery used with `in`.  Nor can you refer to the table being updated in a subquery (without using `join`).  You can, however, switch this to a `join`:

```
UPDATE ledum_orgs lo JOIN
       (SELECT ledum_org_size
        FROM ledum_orgs
        WHERE ledum_org_size = '0'
        ORDER BY ledum_org_name ASC
        LIMIT ".($i*400).", 400
       ) tmp
       ON tmp.ledum_org_size = lo.ledum_org_size
    SET lo.ledum_org_size = :val;
```

It is possible that you can simplify this to:

```
UPDATE ledum_orgs lo
    SET lo.ledum_org_size = :val
    WHERE ledum_org_size = '0'
    ORDER BY ledum_org_name ASC
    LIMIT ".($i*400).", 400
```