# Mysql - Update record from row X to row Y?

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have 20 records, and I want to update row 6 to row 10. I have tried this code but getting an error:

```
UPDATE db_scheduling.tbl_student 
  SET section ='a' 
  WHERE yrlevel = '1' 
  ORDER BY grade DESC 
  LIMIT 5 
  OFFSET 5;
```

It says I have error on the OFFSET part and I don't know if it works in UPDATE query. When I remove the OFFSET 5, it just updates the first 5 rows. Help please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [update multiple rows using limit in mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513206/update-multiple-rows-using-limit-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like this:

```
UPDATE db_scheduling.tbl_student  
    SET section ='a'
    WHERE yrlevel IN (
     SELECT id FROM (
         SELECT yrlevel FROM db_scheduling.tbl_student 
         ORDER BY grade DESC  
         LIMIT 5, 5
     ) tmp
    );
```

Have a look [update multiple rows using limit in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513206/update-multiple-rows-using-limit-in-mysql)

Comment: @LeeSong, perhaps, but clearly something like it works

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a self join with only rows that you want to update

```
UPDATE `tbl_student` s
JOIN (
SELECT id FROM `tbl_student` 
WHERE yrlevel = '1' 
  ORDER BY grade DESC 
  LIMIT 5 
  OFFSET 5
) s1 USING(id)
SET s.section ='a'
```

[`DEMO`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eab71/1)